# Foxhole radio not working

Tags: radio

I tried building a foxhole radio but it didn't work. My razor blade is blued and the antenna is long enough. I don't think my speaker is the problem because I hooked up a voltmeter to it and it showed 0.00 volts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgAm2Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My coil has 50 turns of copper wire covered with varnish.

Comment: What speaker type?

Comment: Where did you come across this dubious looking design?

Comment: @Andyaka it's all over the place, including wikipedia. Sadly, the schematics that go with these never mention the fact that what makes this work is the parasitic inter-winding capacitiy (and that this of course needs tuning...), and that this isn't supposed to work in a world where AM transmitters are rare, and if you're close to one, so that this works energetically, that stands a high chance of transmitting a whole bunch of channels at once, not just one, so that due to lacking selectivity this doesn't work and... You get the picture.

Comment: @Andyaka the original source might be this 1944 [magazine](https://worldradiohistory.com/Archive-Radio-Craft/1940s/Radio-Craft-1944-09.pdf)

Comment: https://www.ebaumsworld.com/jokes/they-walk-among-us/80444286/

Comment: @MarcusMüller I want the OP to explain that but thanks for the link to the old magazine. It was an interesting read.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your speaker, but you have to realize this kind of receiver has a *very* high output impedance: there's nearly no current this can supply to the speaker.

Also, you won't be able to see audio-frequency AC voltage with your voltmeter.

You'll need an [earpiece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_earpiece) (usually, not something you'd call a "speaker") that has a very high impedance.

Think about this: that's a passive circuit, which means all the energy reaching your inner ear has to come from the electromagnetic wave you're picking up with your antenna. That's microwatts, at best.

Your audio amplifier driving a speaker (e.g. in your stereo, or in your smart phone) have powers of 0.1 W to 100 W, depending on how large and loud you want your speakers to be. So, you're off by at least 5 orders of magnitude.

And that assumes your circuit works perfectly well (I don't even think yours really does).

Also, these razorblade diodes are far from deterministic: it's usual that you'd have to spend minutes until you find a spot where it works.

Comment: In the old days you probably won't remember, we used to have available high quality headphones with very high impedance from very fine, tightly wound, wire. Today, almost unobtainable. Have a look [here](http://messui.polygonal-moogle.com/valves/SC199701.pdf) for an article and a means to adapt newer speakers. Also, if you want to make one then look at this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/oChYc16byV8).

Comment: huh, clever, a high-winding ratio signal transformer!

Comment: When I built my first crystal radio, I bought and used a galena crystal from South America from a rock-collector and had to melt lead and pour it in order to seat the crystal. I made the cat's whisker from a needle and built the gimbal system for it. I made the earpiece myself from a magnet, wire, a small metal diaphram I cut by hand, etc. I fabricated every single detail from raw part sources. I didn't buy a headphone. I made it from bits and pieces. Two days ago, I just made and built a replacement towel rack (bathroom) from scraps I had laying about. I still build house doors from scratch.

Comment: Hmm. Just read that 1944 magazine you posted up. I also made a carbon microphone when I was a kid, almost exactly as shown one one of the pages there!! Interesting to read and see that, again. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @jonk Would a crystal earpiece work instead of the headphones? They are readily available.

Comment: @AndrewMorton What I used to call a "crystal headset" is what I described -- oodles and oodles of very fine wire wound up. Then there were these new-fangled "crystal earpieces" that Radio Shack sold for a dollar or so. Not the same thing, memory serving. Those things were "piezos" for audio.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The following points are to be taken care of while building the foxhole radio.

1. Wire antenna around 60 - 120 feet long.
2. A good earth connection to a buried water pipe.
3. Coil former 1.5 - 2" in diameter.
4. 75 to 125 turns of 25 SWG enamelled copper wire for the coil ( greater the former diameter, lesser the turns).
5. Enamel stripped over the coil length to have a slider tap for tuning (utilising coil resonance due to self capacitance).
6. Sensitive high impedance (2 kΩ) headphones.
7. Trials with razor blade / pencil detector only after successful trials with a standard diode detector.

Comment: drop the germanium diode and just use an arbitrary Schottky diode... germanium diodes haven't been in production since about 50 years or more.

Comment: @Marcus Müller, 1N34A germanium diodes are available. https://www.fabtolab.com/components/semiconductors/diode

Comment: that might be,  but they are inferior to Schottky small signal diodes in every way imaginable. There's really no reason to use a Germanium diode.

Comment: @Marcus Müller, Sure, but any available germanium diode would be good enough to tweak the set before trying one's hand with a razor blade detector.

Comment: yes, but Germanium diodes are special "old stock" things that are both harder to get and worse for this application than boring, modern, easily available, cheap Schottky diodes.

Comment: @Marcus Müller, I get it! Thank you. My answer has been amended.